# Navigate to another tab from within MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabcontrol, flutter-navigation

I expected this issue to have a simple solution but I didn't find yet any...

I have few tabs in my app, in one of them I open another screen using

```
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(...
```

Once user clicks on a button in that screen I want to pop it **and** navigate to another tab.

I tried to pass TabController to the relevant tab and its child screen, but this doesn't seem like the simplest solution, and also not easy to accomplish since the controller is not yet defined:

```
tabController = DefaultTabController(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
                 FirstTab(
                    tabController: tabController // <- tabController is not defined yet at this point:(
```

Is there any "global" function to reset the app's "entire" route so it will **both** pop MaterialPageRoute **and** navigate to specific tab ?

Comment: You can use MaterialApp's onGenerateRoute to define navigation rules, but for that you will have to use named navigation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will check that option. I hoped there will be a simpler solution...

Comment: also, according to this documentation named route is not recommended for most applications: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to call Navigator's push **synchronously** and check for its returned value. Then when I want to navigate to another tab I simply send true indication in Navigator's pop.

This is how my navigation method looks like, notice I had to add a short delay before navigating to another tab, not sure why, but it didn't work without it:

```
  _navigateToDetailsScreen() async {
      bool shouldNavigateToHomeTab = await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailsScreen()),
           ));
      if (shouldNavigateToHomeTab) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
             DefaultTabController.of(context)!.animateTo(0);
          });
      }
  }
```

And this is how I call pop:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

This looks like the simplest solution for me, and so far I didn't find any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html)

Comment: but then I need to initialize a *new* instance of the tab I want to navigate to ? isn't it a problem ? shouldn't I navigate to the *same* instance somehow ?

Comment: which Route subclass I should use in that case ?